# So much trouble trying to redirect non-www and http to www and https in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

This is really doing my head in.

There are lots of different examples of htaccess rules to redirect from non-www to www and http to https, it's getting really confusing.

I want to be able to rewrite anything in those combinations to https and www.

The below code is just telling me too many redirects are happening, and I dont understand it. Can anyone adjust the code and explain what's causing the redirects?

By the way, the below is EXACTLY how my htaccess file appears.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Try changing `%{HTTPS} off [OR]` to `%{ENV:HTTPS} !on [OR]`.

Comment: Ah that's fixed it perfectly. Man that's annoying, but thanks!

Comment: No problem, I had this problem myself a while ago and it took so long until I found a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [OR]
```

Then it should work without issue. You will need to clear your cache to show the new change.